# Does pointwise nilpotency imply global nilpotency?

Tags: abstract-algebra, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, nilpotence

Is there a compact  Haussdorf space  $X$  and  $C^{*}$ algebra  $A$ with  a  continuous  map  $f:X\to A$, such that  $f(x)\in A$ is  a  nilpotent element,  $\forall x \in X$,  but $f$  is not a nilpotent element of the algebra $C(X,A)$, the space of $A$-valued continuous maps on $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Take $A=B(H)$ for $H$ infinite-dimensional (or any other algebra that has nilpotent elements of arbitrarily large degree), and choose a sequence of elements $a_n\in A$ such that $a_n^n=0$, $a_n^{n-1}\neq 0$, and $\|a_n\|=1/n$.  Taking $X=\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$, there is then $f\in C(X,A)$ given by $f(n)=a_n$ and $f(\infty)=0$.  Each value of $f$ is nilpotent, but there is no single $n$ such that $f(x)^n=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thank you very  much for your interesting answer. Is there  an example of  a  compact  connected X with this property. note that the nilpotency-order is  not  an upper semi   continuous  function.

Comment: Sure, you can make the domain be $[0,1]$ instead by choosing the $a_n$ to commute, letting $f(1/n)=a_n$, $f(0)=0$, and interpolating linearly in between (the condition that the $a_n$ commute is just so that the linear interpolations will still be nilpotent).

Comment: yes. very nice idea.

Comment: What about if we require  that "f is  nilpotent valued of unit norm"?

Comment: Let $b\in A$ be nilpotent of norm $2$ and satisfy $ba_n=a_nb=0$ for all $n$, and consider $g(x)=(b+f(x))/\|b+f(x)\|$.